# How complete this function this code with assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

This is a section code of assembly:

```
_load_gdtr:             ; void load_gdtr(int limit, int addr);
         MOV       AX,[ESP+4]   ; limit
         MOV       [ESP+6],AX
         LGDT      [ESP+6]
         RET
```

**CALL WAY:** Call this func with two arguments **limit = 0x0000ffff addr = 0x00270000**.

**PROBLEM:** In my mind, **limit** and **addr** like this [FF FF 00 00 00 00 27 00](low -> high), but the result is this [FF FF 00 00 00 27 00] on book, I don't know this is why(memory save way is littleendian).

Comment: You have to specify the used ABI to explain what is on stack upon function entry (or show the caller, how it calls the function). If I would guess a naive two 32b values on stack, then [esp+4] is limit, [esp+8] is addr. Then upon entry the memory at esp+4: `FF FF 00 00 00 00 27 00`. After MOVs esp+4: `FF FF FF FF 00 00 27 00`. Why don't you simply use debugger and memory view to stack to see yourself, what's happening there? (I don't see how you can get `[FF FF 00 00 00 27 00]` in memory. .. and I don't know what `LGDT` expects, so I don't know what is wanted)

Comment: Because I am learning how to make an os from scratch, I use the assembly compiler is nask that language rules is the book author accodes to nasm rebuild.

Comment: Ped7g ; LGDT (in 32-bit code) will take a memory operand that contains a 6 byte structure. The first word of the structure is the size of the GDT and the next 4 bytes are the linear address of the physical GDT. This code is effectively using the parameters on the stack to temporarily build a 6-byte GDT record that can be used by LGDT to load the GDT register. In this case a record that says the GDT is 65536 byte (0xffff+1) with a base linear address of 0x00270000

Comment: I am learning make an os from scratch. I write this code on windows, but this env cant't give a debuger program for me, so I can't view memory with myself. I hope GDTR low 16 bits save **limit**, high 32 bits save **addr**.The assembly grammar is like nasm and I run this code in 32 bits mode.The caller is `void load_gdtr(int limit, int addr)`.

Comment: @Michael Petch But I don't know the parameter how save in stack. Like this `FF FF 00 00 00 27 00` or this `FF FF 00 00 00 00 27 00`

Comment: You can't `lgdt` under windows AFAIK, that would be security breach (unless there's "user" level of GDT, which I'm not aware of, but I never studied the x86 OS-internals). If you are working on OS from scratch, you need some virtual PC to boot it on, "bochs" is used in many other questions for this, also contains some debugger, so you can debug there. To call this function with those params you have to be in 32b mode already and do `push dword 0x00270000` `push dword 0x0000FFFF` `call _load_gdtr`. In 32b mode return address on stack is 4B, so the `esp+4` and `esp+6` is correct then.

Comment: BTW, it takes some times to learn x86 assembly, are you sure you want the additional burden of learning also full x86 architecture and OS related things together with that? Maybe you should spend few weeks learning just x86 asm basics programming some simple DOS/win32/linux apps, so you will get idea about basic things like `push` `call` `ret`, and how numbers are stored into memory.

Comment: 0x00270000 in little endian is 0x00 0x00 0x27 0x00 . Each of the bytes are in reverse order. The byte organization of the 2 separate 32-bit dwords placed on the stack would be 0xff 0xff 0x00 0x00 / 0x00 0x00 0x27 0x00. After the moves are done and before the LGDT it looks like 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff / 0x00 0x00 0x27 0x00 . [ESP+6] is the memory address for LGDT so the 6-byte loaded into the GDT register would be 0xff 0xff 0x00 0x00 0x27 0x00

Comment: The `FF FF 00 00 00 27 00` is simply wrong (if it is in book). You either have original two 32b values 0xFFFF and 0x270000, then you have in memory `FF FF 00 00 _ 00 00 27 00` (added underscore between values), or after executing those two MOVs you have starting at esp+6: `FF FF _ 00 00 27 00` (two zeroes from "limit" are overwritten by `FF FF`). You can't have three zeroes between, from that code above and those arguments.

Comment: @Ped7g You are right. I think I've got answer. Thank you.

Comment: As Ped says if that is in a book or tutorial it is wrong. I did find some obscure reference in a Chinese Text and in that text it appears they got it wrong. It should have been `[FF FF 00 00 27 00]` and `[FF FF FF FF 00 00 27 00]` . A rough translation of the erroneous text was _In order to execute LGDT, the authors want to arrange them as [FF FF 00 27 00 00]. So first read the first 0xffff "MOV AX, [ESP + 4]" and then write to [ESP + 6]. The result is [FF FF FF FF 00 27 00 00]. If you read 6 bytes from [ESP + 6], it is the result you want, as shown in the following figure:_

Comment: @MichaelPetch The book give me a wrong answer. But now I have got this. Thank you.